# System.Text.UTF8Encoding().GetBytes Adding newline

Tags: c#, csv, encoding

I wanna add new Lines right now i get all on one line.

This is the my code:

```
csv = csv +  model.Id + ','+ fname+  ',' + lname+ ',' + Email + ',' + Phone + System.NewLine; 
return File(new System.Text.UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(csv), "text/csv", "PaymentsChecked.csv");
```

PS: I tried "\n" but in vain

Comment: It seems you are adding a newline (only) **at the end** of the resulting overall csv string. Where do you want the newline to appear? Add a newline at exactly the position within the resulting csv string you want it to be...

Comment: What assembly exports `System.NewLine`?

Comment: Please provide real [MCVE]. The line you have currently does not compile to start with and does not explain what problem you have... Also clarifying your expectations (i.e. "Notepad should show new lines" or "vim should show new lines" or "when rendered as HTML should show new lines") would be nice addition as part of [edit].

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try using the `Environment.NewLine` instead of `System.NewLine`.
And it is also a good practice to simplify that long statement `new System.Text.UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(csv)`.

```
csv = csv +  model.Id + ','+ fname+  ',' + lname+ ',' + Email + ',' + Phone + System.NewLine; 
return File(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(csv), "text/csv", "PaymentsChecked.csv");
```

It works properly, because the last two bytes are 13 - for carriage return ('\r') and 10 - for a new line ('\n').
If you still do not get the new line, I can certainly tell you that it is not because of the code above but maybe because of your further implementation.